# NX workspace, how to change an Angular app name with the the cli?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, nrwl-nx

I have NX workspace with some apps and the product decided to change one of the apps name,
how can I do it without manually change the app's folders names, modules names, all the importing paths, NX settings etc'?

Same app, same location, only different name.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since [Nx 8.12](https://blog.nrwl.io/nx-8-12-distributed-caching-improved-dependency-detection-better-support-for-buildable-libraries-6f7cec17b83f) you can do it by using the `move` schematic (or `mv`) to 'move' the app to the **same** place but with the new wanted name.

For example, if I want to rename my 'oldNG' app to be called 'newNG', I can do that like so:

`nx g @nrwl/workspace:move --project oldNG newNG`

Or `nx g mv --project oldNG newNG` if I want to rename app from my default collection. (provisioned in angular.json).

If I want to move this app to different place- I just need to include the destination in the new name of the app, like so:

`nx g @nrwl/workspace:move --project oldNG destination/newNG`

Read more:
https://nx.dev/latest/angular/plugins/workspace/schematics/move

Answer (score 1):

Use @nx/workspace:move

For example:

```
nx g @nx/workspace:move --projectName old-project-name --destination apps/new-project-name --newProjectName new-project-name
```

This commad move and rename your project.

Read more: https://nx.dev/nx-api/workspace/generators/move